# Swiper touch slider - Not sliding

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I'm creating a swiper in jQuery. Im using Swiper touch slider - It's not working on my main domain. Only thing I can think of is that another JS file is overriding it? But I removed all of my JS files and its still not working. Heres the HTML code

```
        <div class="device">
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-container" style="cursor: -webkit-grab;">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper" style="width: 3200px; height: 560px; transform: translate3d(-1920px, 0px, 0px); transition-duration: 0.3s;">
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate" style="width: 513px; height: 560px;">
        <div class="content-slide">
        <p class="title">Slide with HTML</p>
        <p>You can put any HTML inside of slide with any layout, not only images, even another Swiper!</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="width: 513px; height: 560px;"> <img src="images/slider1-1.png"> </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="width: 513px; height: 560px;"> <img src="images/slider1-2.png"> </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-visible swiper-slide-active" style="width: 513px; height: 560px;">
        <div class="content-slide">
        <p class="title">Slide with HTML</p>
        <p>You can put any HTML inside of slide with any layout, not only images, even another Swiper!</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate" style="width: 513px; height: 560px;"> <img src="images/slider1-1.png"> </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pagination"><span class="swiper-pagination-switch"></span><span class="swiper-pagination-switch"></span><span class="swiper-pagination-switch swiper-visible-switch swiper-active-switch"></span></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
        <script>
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: true,
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        spaceBetween: 0
        });
        </script>   

        This is the link to Swiper:
        http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WM4Hd_krIdU

        I also added in at the footer:
        <script src="js/swiper.js"></script>        
        <script src="js/swiper.min.js"></script>        
        <script src="js/swiper.jquery.js"></script>     
        <script src="js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should develop your html according to the following template:

```
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
<!-- Additional required wrapper -->
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    ...
</div>
<!-- If we need pagination -->
<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

<!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

<!-- If we need scrollbar -->
<div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

load the minificated version (.min.js) **OR** the not minified (.js)

include the swiper initialization script in the very end of body (right before closing  tag)

you can read the docs here : http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/#.WNsOA98xA8o